# Connection with battery charger IC IP5209

Tags: battery-charging, integrated-circuit, schematics

I am very new to electronics and need some help with understanding how to read a part of a schematic

I am using the IP5209 Battery Management IC, and don't understand these example schematic on a particular pin

[image]
<sub>Source: http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/e5285ef970d502a38b9466569d9487de.pdf</sub>

Where does NTC (pin 6) go? This pin is a temperature monitor and according to the datasheet supposed to be connected to a voltage regulator, but this datasheet makes it seem like it's connected to the VREG pin?

Any advice on how to read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does NTC (pin 6) go?

It depends.

If you need an NTC, you'll have to populate the components as follows:

- R4: 120 kΩ 0603
- R6: 170 kΩ 0603
- R7: 100K/25C NTC 1% 0603

If you don't need the NTC function:

- R4: 2 MΩ 0603
- R6: 1 MΩ 0603
- R7: unplaced

> This pin is a temperature monitor and according to the datasheet supposed to be connected to a voltage regulator, but this datasheet makes it seem like it's connected to the VREG pin?

It is connected to `VREG` via R4 and R6. And if you need NTC functionality, the NTC is connected in parallel to R6.

---

EDIT

> So if I didn't want the NTC function, I would just remove the R7 part, and connect the end of R4 to the VREG wire? Also, would I move the R6 Resistor up next to the R4 or leave it there? I don't understand why it would stay down there haha

The [datasheet](http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/e5285ef970d502a38b9466569d9487de.pdf) says that you need to apply 1 V to the NTC pin, if you don't need the NTC function. You can achieve that by placing R4=2 MΩ, R6=1 MΩ, as stated above. As long as V<sub>NTC</sub>=1 V you should be fine. For example R4=200 kΩ, R6=100 kΩ is fine as well.

(1 V applied to the NTC pin indicates a temperature of about 25 °C.)

Comment: So if I didn't want the NTC function, I would just remove the R7 part, and connect the end of R4 to the VREG wire? Also, would I move the R6 Resistor up next to the R4 or leave it there? I don't understand why it would stay down there haha